# Update if record already exist but insert if record does not exist

Tags: mysql

How do i do this. Here is my code`

```
$insert = "REPLACE INTO drinks SET
name='".$name2."', category=' ".$category2." ', date=CURDATE()";
if (@mysql_query($insert)) {
echo '<h4 class="alert_info">Drinks added</h4>';
} else {
echo 'Error adding event: ' .
mysql_error() . '';
}
```

Comment: There are several ways, is it more likely that the record exists, or that it doesn't.

Comment: What's your `drinks` table structure? Which columns are the indexes?

Answer (score 5):

Generally, what you are looking for is called "[upsert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29)" (ie UPdate or inSERT). From this link apparently for MySQL the syntax is:

> INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

With [more info from the MySql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: MERGE INTO TABLE_NAME USING table_reference ON (condition)... i dont understand this line wat should i use as table reference and what should i put in (condition)

Comment: Nice, I never knew about this. I'd just update, test for error and insert if not.

Comment: Well the MySQL manual has as as example: `INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;` So following update put what to do if there record already exists because if it doesn't it'll treat it like a regular `INSERT` statement